# How to Use atTask REST API with Federated SSO

Tags: attask

I need to be able to close tasks through the rest AP but our organization is using federated login using Active Directory. While, I can get read-only access to a users tasks by taking advantage of cookie authentication, there is apparently no documented way to acquire a session id that would give me write-access. Hitting the login link with username/password does not work due to the federated login. Is there an alternate way have authenticated write-access on a per-user basis (not using administrative accounts) ?

Comment: SSO implemented using web form and relaystate. So, you should use some web browser component in your application or made all requests/responses programmatically.

Comment: @dtabuenc I am facing same issue. Could you please help me to fix this by providing your input.

Answer (score 0):

In the user settings I had to check the box to allow users to use both SSO and standard login and password. There does not appear to be a way to do it otherwise. As no password is sent to the user they don't really notice the difference.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to use the API using a federated login you can either.

1. Allow this user to bypass SSO under their user setting in attask by unchecking "only allow SSO login"
2. You could also setup an apiKey to use which works the same as a session ID but does not expire. (this is only for admins)

Info on setting up an apiKey can be found here
https://developers.attask.com/api-docs/#Basics

In your case where you want a non admin account to perform the calls you will allow users to authenticate using AtTask credentials.

Comment: I have a small doubt regarding non admin user which got created through user provisioning. How we will login with that user without knowing the password?